# how to add information at the start of the file using perl

Tags: perl

i have c file and i need to add some information at the begging of the c file. I have one hash table with keys as the numbers and values as the strings. by using that table i am searching if the string found i am adding information to c file. i did this by using script i posted in " [add information to a file using perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687243/add-information-to-a-file-using-perl)" question. now i need to add information at the beginging of the c file if i found string.In my script i am adding before the string.
what should i do now.
 thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Cross-posted from the answer I just gave on [the SitePoint forums](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?788857-perl-script-to-add-information-to-a-file) to what appears to be the same question.)

Sadly, there's no way to insert information at the beginning of a file without having to rewrite the whole thing, so you'll need to read in the entire file (rather than just one line at a time), determine which string(s) appear in the contents, write the corresponding information item(s) to a new file, and (finally!) write the original contents to the new file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Slurp;

my %strings = (
  'string1' => "information \n",
  'string2' => "information2 \n",
  'string3' => "information3 \n",
);
my $test_string = "(" . join("|", keys %strings) . ")";

# First make a list of all matched strings (including the number of times
# each was found, although I assume that's not actually relevant)

my $code = read_file('c.c');
my %found;
while ($code =~ /$test_string/g) {
  $found{$1}++;
}

# If %found is empty, we didn't find anything to insert, so no need to rewrite
# the file

exit unless %found;

# Write the prefix data to the new file followed by the original contents

open my $out, '>', 'c.c.new';
for my $string (sort keys %found) {
  print $out $strings{$string};
}

print $out $code;

# Replace the old file with the new one
rename 'c.c.new', 'c.c';
```

Comment: Hi, i tried your code but it doesnt give any errors and output also.if you see my code what i am posted in "add information to a file using perl" question.I have two hash table and i used that two and i found stings in c file and i added information before the string in c file.but in your code i dint found where did you added information to c file.sorry for asking like that.@Dave

Comment: @viswa: The new information is written to the file by the `for my $string (sort keys %found)` loop. Since the question on SitePoint specified adding the information to the beginning of an existing file, this code just modifies the file on disk and doesn't provide any output to the terminal. Remove `$out` from the two `print $out...` statements if you want the changed version to show up on-screen instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping and now i tried and its working good.

Answer (score 2):

This is a FAQ.

[How do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change%2c-delete%2c-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file%2c-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file%3f)